# javascript: manipulate array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I have an array like this:

```
arr = [
  {name:'Tom', a:1, b:1, c:0},
  {name:'Sam', a:0, b:1, c:1},
  {name:'Tom', a:0, b:0, c:1},
  {name:'Sam', a:1, b:2, c:1},
  {name: 'Jack', a:1, b:2, c:0}
]
```

and I need to sum the properties of the objects with the same name and then to slice duplicates:

```
arr = [
  {name:'Tom', a:1, b:1, c:1},
  {name:'Sam', a:1, b:3, c:2},
  {name: 'Jack', a:1, b:2, c:0}
]
```

How is it possible in pure JavaScript?

Comment: Is Javascript a Turing complete langage? Yes, it's *possible*…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proposal for random properties, with a hash table.

```js
var arr = [{ name: 'Tom', a: 1, b: 1, c: 0 }, { name: 'Sam', a: 0, b: 1, c: 1 }, { name: 'Tom', a: 0, b: 0, c: 1 }, { name: 'Sam', a: 1, b: 2, c: 1 }, { name: 'Jack', a: 1, b: 2, c: 0 }],
    grouped = [];

arr.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a.name]) {
        this[a.name] = { name: a.name };
        grouped.push(this[a.name]);
    }
    Object.keys(a).forEach(function (k) {
        if (k !== 'name') {
            this[k] = (this[k] || 0) + a[k];
        }
    }, this[a.name]);
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(grouped);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`for loop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)** and **[`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** with an object for index reference.

```
// object reference for index
var obj = {},
  //  variable for delete count
  dc = 0,
  // variable for length of array
  len = arr.length;

// iterate over the object array
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  // get the current object
  var v = arr[i - dc];
  // check property defined in reference object
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(v.name)) {
    // if already defined add the values
    arr[obj[v.name]].a += v.a;
    arr[obj[v.name]].b += v.b;
    arr[obj[v.name]].c += v.c;
    // if there is random properties are there then use 
    // Object.keys to get the property name value array
    // and iterate and update the properties ( except `name` )

    // remove the current element and increment delete count
    arr.splice(i - dc++, 1);
  } else {
    // else define the index reference in object
    obj[v.name] = i - dc;
  }
}
```

```js
var arr = [{
  name: 'Tom',
  a: 1,
  b: 1,
  c: 0
}, {
  name: 'Sam',
  a: 0,
  b: 1,
  c: 1
}, {
  name: 'Tom',
  a: 0,
  b: 0,
  c: 1
}, {
  name: 'Sam',
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 1
}, {
  name: 'Jack',
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 0
}];

var obj = {},
  dc = 0,
  len = arr.length;

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  var v = arr[i - dc];
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(v.name)) {
    arr[obj[v.name]].a += v.a;
    arr[obj[v.name]].b += v.b;
    arr[obj[v.name]].c += v.c;
    arr.splice(i - dc++, 1);
  } else {
    obj[v.name] = i - dc;
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a second array. Then, for each element of your first array, iterate the first array and push the sum of the properties to the new array. On each duplicate you have to delete the entry out of the first array. And tada...